# How can I have a common background color across multiple wordpress blocks?

Tags: wordpress

On a Wordpress page I have a number of subtopics. I'm trying to separate each of those subtopics into their own blocks so that it looks more neat and organized.

Here is a crude example of what I'm trying to achieve in wordpress:

```
    A Heading H2 block
    A paragraph (containing the main body) block
    A short code block
    A short code block
```

The section highlighted above is a bunch of wordpress blocks put inside a single, unbroken color. The idea is to have this for each subtopic to improve readability.

All my attempts color individual blocks with an ugly white space between them rather than a constant color across multiple blocks.

**How can I change the background color (or create a "visible panel" for lack of better words) in this manner?** I would like to implement this without modifying the CSS file. I'm using a Hestia theme file in case that helps.

Comment: You mean, you have one page and in this page has content with multiple blocks (section), right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes. That is correct. And for those multiple blocks I need a common color background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not received any responses so far. I cannot mark this question as a duplicate from another site. Hence, I'm posting the solution that worked for me over here. I tried updating Wordpress to 5.3 and using the built-in "group" method. Steps I followed:

1. Basically, you select a bunch of wordpress blocks, Just select (highlight) them normally as you would select any ordinary text.
2. Right-click and then choose group.
3. Apply a color from the right panel, options menu

This is a simple, straight-forward method. No code changes required other than updating wordpress to the latest version. applies the effect that I was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Right-clicking didn't work for me. On the floating toolbar, I clicked on the three dots, chose Group. That made a uniform block so that none of the blocks stuck out into the margins anymore. However, another step was needed to fill in the white spaces.

To fill in the white spaces, I had to repeat the process for adding background colour. For details on how to do this, see my blog post with screenshots "Background Colours and Grouping on WordPress Blocks"  at https://sarahbowmansite.wordpress.com/2023/11/06/background-colours-and-grouping-on-wordpress-blocks/.

I wrote it so I would know how to do it next time but I'm also sharing it here in case it helps someone else.